# Error starting virtual machine - Not enough resources available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to start an virtual machine on Google Cloud.  I get an error that there isn't enough resources to fulfill my request.

I have been using Google Cloud for about one week to study and try automated trading systems through Metatrader5 on a Linux server.

I was able to use my machine using VNC server, even this morning, but suddenly all my machines (are all on same location) started to show an error when trying to start:

> The zone 'projects/metatrader-227016/zones/southamerica-east1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

I read about moving my instance to another region, but it's not a simple instruction. What is strange is that my VM is really small and lightweight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem appears with Google Cloud Compute once in a while. You have several options:

1. Wait. The resource will eventually be available.
2. Resize your instance to a different size. A different instance size might be available.
3. Change regions.
4. If you have paid support, open a support ticket with Google Cloud Support.

The smaller instance sizes are cheaper and therefore in higher demand.

To move an instance to a different region:

1. Login to the Google Cloud Console. Go to Compute Engine -> Disks.
2. Select your disk for the instance you plan to move.
3. At the top of the screen click `CREATE IMAGE`. Give the image a name. For Family enter anything you want but remember it.
4. Once the image creation completes, create a new Compute Engine VM in the region that you want.  When creating the new VM, under `Boot disk`, click Change. You will find your image under the tab `Custom images`.

Comment: I faced this same problem with Azure as well. Cloud is not infinite, people have to understand it and create solution around that :)

Comment: This answer is very good. Additional you can also do this directly from copying the instance. Since the instance is not running in that region, you can go to `Compute Engine > VM Instances` and find your instance that can't start. Click on the instance to open the `VM instance details page`. Now on the top click `CREATE SIMILAR`. This will make a copy of your VM Instance's details and will try to create a new one. Just change the `Region` and `Zone` section and create the instance. After successful creation, the instance will be running in another zone.